# SplitEmptyFunction doesn't split empty function

Tags: c++, clang-format

This is (part of) my .clang-format:

```
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
BraceWrapping:
    AfterFunction: true
    SplitEmptyFunction: true
```

And even though SplitEmptyFunction is set to true, it still formats my code like this:

```cpp
void foo()
{}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `SplitEmptyRecord` is the setting I was looking for, that is kinda weird, looks like a bug.